# Record OSC for Non-Realtime-Synthesis

Tags: supercollider

How do I:

1. record OSC input to a control file during realtime synthesis
2. Use that control file for non-realtime synthesis

The reason to do it is to perform at low quality, and then render at high quality.

Comment: hey, you are better off asking at sc-users http://www.beast.bham.ac.uk/research/sc_mailing_lists.shtml